# for block in scala with a yield

Tags: scala

Where is this documented in the Odersky book:

```
def bestBuyerPrice: Option[Price] = bids.headOption

for {
   price1 <- bestBuyerPrice
   price2 <- bestAskerPrice
} yield (price1.price + price2.price) / 2
```

What is this syntax called? Where is this documented?

What is the generator for? Isn't bestBuyerPrice either `None` or `Some`?

Answer (score 3):

There are two things going on here.

Firstly, as already observed, using `for` is just a shorthand for calling `map` and `flatMap` on a collection. A key thing to note is that the type of the collection returned by `for` is the type of the collection in the first `<-` line.

Secondly, you can treat an `Option` value as if it were a collection with `0` or `1` elements. Calling `map` on an `Option` will return `None` if the option is `None`, or `Some(y)` if the option is `Some(x)`. Calling `flatMap` on a collection of `Option`s will remove all the `None` values from the collection and extract the value of all the `Some` options.

So putting this together, your code returns an `Option` because `bestBuyerPrice` is an option. If either `bestBuyerPrice` or `bestAskerPrice` is `None` then the result is `None` because that is what `map`/`flatMap` returns. If they are both `Some(x)` then the result is `Some(y)` where `y` is result of the `yield`.

Comment: What do you mean calling map on an `Option` will return `None`? Show me some code? Where is this documented?

Comment: Calling `map` on an `Option` value will return `None` **if the value is `None`**. If the value is `Some(x)` it will return `Some(y)` where `y` is the result of applying the argument of `map` to the value `x`. See https://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/scala/Option.html

Comment: can you give me a code example and I'll give you credit!

Comment: Is it just `Some("a", "b").map(_)`?

Answer (score 2):

I don't have the latest edition of the book, but look for "for comprehensions", essentially is syntactic sugar for chaining flatMaps and map.

See https://docs.scala-lang.org/tour/for-comprehensions.html

Comment: https://www.artima.com/pins1ed/for-expressions-revisited.html and https://scala-lang.org/files/archive/spec/2.13/06-expressions.html#for-comprehensions-and-for-loops